# Why does my DBContext.SaveChanges() method change values of the object I'm adding?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dbcontext

I am adding an object to a DBContext collection. Before saving it to the collection, the variables within that object are all correct, after saving it, and looking inside of the DBContext collection using the debugging tools VS2012 has, I notice that all the values inside of the object change. Here is the relevant code:

```
public class AdmissionsStoreEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}

public void AddToCart(Product product)
{
    // Get the matching cart and product instances
    var cartItem = storeDB.Carts.SingleOrDefault(
        c => c.CartId == ShoppingCartId
        && c.ProductId == product.ProductId);

    if (cartItem == null)
    {
        // Create a new cart item if no cart item exists
        cartItem = new Cart
        {
            ProductId = product.ProductId,
            Product = product,
            CartId = ShoppingCartId,
            Count = 1,
            DateCreated = DateTime.Now
        };

        // storeDB is my AdmissionsStoreEntities() object.
        storeDB.Carts.Add(cartItem);
    }
    else
    {
        // If the item does exist in the cart, then add one to the quantity.
        cartItem.Count++;
    }

    // Save Changes (where the changes occur)
    storeDB.SaveChanges();
}
```

So for example, before saving the cartItem object to storeDB.Carts, the values are as follows:

- ProductId = 5
- RecordId = 0
- Count = 1
- Product.ProductID = 5
- Product.CategoryID = 5

After saving the changes, the values change for the cartItem, (I also noticed the values are changed for the original object passed into the method). Here are the values afterwards

- ProductId = 7
- RecordID = 9
- Count = 1
- Product.ProductID = 7
- Product.CategoryID = 7

Why is this happening? If needed I can supply more code.

As requested, this is how I am getting my ShoppingCartId.

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(int id)
    {
        // Retrieve the product from our ViewData object that holds all current  data        in the SharePoint list
        var addedProduct = ((List<Product>)ViewData["AllProducts"]).Find(x => x.ProductId == id);

        // Get our cart instance.
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

        // Add product to cart.
        cart.AddToCart(addedProduct);

        // Go back to the main store page for more shopping
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

public static ShoppingCart GetCart(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        var cart = new ShoppingCart();
        cart.ShoppingCartId = cart.GetCartId(context);
        return cart;
    }

public string GetCartId(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        if (context.Session[CartSessionKey] == null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.User.Identity.Name))
            {
                context.Session[CartSessionKey] = context.User.Identity.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                Guid tempCartId = Guid.NewGuid();

                context.Session[CartSessionKey] = tempCartId.ToString();
            }
        }
        return context.Session[CartSessionKey].ToString();
    }
```

Links to my Cart and ShoppingCart models are at the following links, as requested by Rob:

- http://pastebin.com/M3rCscWE
- http://pastebin.com/RDGTwttP

Results of debug code Rob provided:

- http://pastebin.com/t7NF3kfZ

Comment: Can you show from where these values you are getting? I mean CardId in both the cases and DateCreated as well.

Comment: If you suspect the save is causing it, can you do `Debug.WriteLine(cartItem.ProductId)` before **and** after `storeDB.SaveChanges();`? to prove or disprove it.

Comment: Can you post your Cart and ShoppingCart models?

Comment: Have you checked your database directly to see if the values are being saved incorrectly? Can you print cartItem.ProductId before and after the save?

Comment: Sorry, print cartItem.RecordId

Comment: Can you add these debug statements and show us the results: http://pastebin.com/4smC0iPZ

Comment: I used Debug.WriteLine before and after the save.

Before the save, cartItem.ProductId is 5.

After the save, cartItem.ProductId is 19.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/t7NF3kfZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Try removing `Product = product`:

```
if (cartItem == null)
    {
        // Create a new cart item if no cart item exists
        cartItem = new Cart
        {
            ProductId = product.ProductId,
            //Product = product,
            CartId = ShoppingCartId,
            Count = 1,
            DateCreated = DateTime.Now
        };

        // storeDB is my AdmissionsStoreEntities() object.
        storeDB.Carts.Add(cartItem);
    }
```

Settting the ProductId should do the trick, you don't need the actual object.

Comment: 'ShoppingCartId' is grabbed from 'HttpContextBase.User.Identity.Name' if the user is logged in. Otherwise the program creates a Guid for the session. 'cartItem' is coming back as null everytime because the 'storeDB.SaveChanges' is changing the values my query is looking for at the beginning of the 'AddToCart()' method.

Comment: And the Guid is created only once right? Can you provide the CartId and DateCreated values for before/after save?

Comment: Before Save: cartId = NHA\\rduffing
             DateCreated = 3/28/2013 10:34:47 AM

After Save: cartId = NHA\\rduffing
            DateCreated = 3/28/2013 10:34:47 AM

            No changes there.

Comment: Is CartId the Primary Key for the Cart object, or is it the reference to the ShoppingCart object?

Comment: I posted by Cart and ShoppingCart models are you requested.

Comment: My guess is that when you pass in Product, it wasn't retrieved from the DbContext. Therefore, DbContext didn't know how to update it and just assigned a new Id primary key for it. You probably can just change that method to accept ProductId.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think this may be a side effect of using a static factory method in what is effectively a multi-threaded environment (ASP.NET).

Here's what you've got:

```
public static ShoppingCart GetCart(HttpContextBase context)
{
    var cart = new ShoppingCart();
    cart.ShoppingCartId = cart.GetCartId(context);
    return cart;
}
```

You get different values for cart.GetCartId(context) depending on which `context` you pass, but because this is a static method you only have one copy of the method and its internal variables.  If two people call it at the same time, you can have the value of `cart.GetCartId()` assigned to a different shopping cart than intended.

In your situation I would create a new constructor for `ShoppingCart` and use it instead of your static factory method:

```
public ShoppingCart(HttpContextBase context)
{
    ShoppingCartId = GetCartId(context);
}
```

Comment: It's getting the ShoppingCart based on a variable stored in Session, so it should be unique to the session.

Comment: You're right that a better way to do it is in a constructor, but I don't think that's the root of the issue.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it did not work. The values still change.